# How can I unit-test the not writabble field?

Tags: unit-test

If the value registered in the LastLoginDate field in the User object has passed 30 days, it will execute ◯◯, otherwise it will write a batch program to execute XX.

When trying to test this program,
I'd like to create test data for which LastLoginDate is 30 days old and test data not 30 days ago, but since LastLoginDate is not writable, I can not do it.

Since data can not be tampered, I tried creating mock with reference to the following,

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_stub_api.htm?search_text=System.StubProvider

I do not know how to return a dummy for getQueryLocator.

How can I unit-test the not writabble field?

The program code is below

```
global class BatchUser implements Database.Batchable<sObject>, Database.Stateful {

    global String errorMessage = '';

    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
        String query = 'SELECT Id, IsActive, LastLoginDate, CreatedDate FROM User WHERE IsActive = TRUE AND UserType != \'Guest\'';
        return UserDao.getQueryLocator(query);
    }

    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<sObject> scope) {
        List<User> users = (List<User>)scope;

        for (User u : users) {
            u.IsActive = (u.LastLoginDate == null) ? ! AAAService.isPassed(u.CreatedDate.getTime(), 6) : ! AAAService.isPassed(u.LastLoginDate.getTime(), 6);
        }

        List<Database.SaveResult> results = Database.update(users, false);
        Integer i = 0;
        for (Database.SaveResult result : results) {
            if (!result.isSuccess()) {
                Database.Error error = result.getErrors()[0];
                this.errorMessage += error.getMessage() + '\n';
            }
            i++;
        }
    }

    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
    }

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The general solution to this problem is to use a separate class for your query (known as the [Selector layer - see Trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/apex_patterns_dsl/units/apex_patterns_dsl_learn_selector_l_principles)) and then mock the results of this Selector class to return mocked `LastLoginDate`

Mocking can be done using the techniques shown here in the [andyinthecloud blog](https://andyinthecloud.com/2015/03/22/unit-testing-with-apex-enterprise-patterns-and-apexmocks-part-1/) - see both Part1 and 2.

Actually setting a value for the field will most likely require using JSON that you then serialize into the SObject. This can be done easily with [this GitHub lib](https://github.com/mattaddy/SObjectFabricator). or, you can construct the JSON manually as a string constant.

Answer (score -3):

Answer to

> I do not know how to return a dummy for getQueryLocator.

You need to insert some records before you call your batch apex.

As you query locator will work on

```
String query = 'SELECT Id, IsActive, LastLoginDate, CreatedDate FROM User WHERE IsActive = TRUE AND UserType != \'Guest\'';
    return UserDao.getQueryLocator(query);
```

You should have user records inserted in your test class which this query can actually work on.

After insertion of user records just use ->

```
YourBatchClass b = new YourBatchClass(); //call the batch

Database.executeBatch(b);
```

Comment: Thank you for answering.
Although it is about putting data, since LastLoginDate is not writable, it can not register data.

Comment: I don't think this is possible. You can create users see here (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_tools_runas.htm) but not set last login.