User.LastLoginDate is not not writable in test class using salesforce
My test class:
@isTest
public class DeactivateInactiveUsersBatchTest {

    @testSetup
    static void setup() {
        // Create sample User records with LastLoginDate more than a year ago and active
        Profile standardUserProfile = [SELECT Id,Name FROM Profile WHERE Name = 'Standard User'];
        
        List<User> users = new List<User>();
        for (Integer i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            users.add(new User(
                FirstName = 'Test',
                LastName = 'User' + i,
                Username = 'testusers' + i + '@example.com',
                Email = 'testusers' + i + '@example.com',
                EmailEncodingKey = 'UTF-8',
                LanguageLocaleKey = 'en_US',
                LocaleSidKey = 'en_US',
                TimeZoneSidKey = 'America/Los_Angeles',
                ProfileId = standardUserProfile.Id,
                Alias = 'tuser' + i,
                IsActive = true,
                LastLoginDate='2019-01-01'
            ));
        }
        insert users;
    }

    @isTest
    static void testDeactivateInactiveUsersBatch() {
        // Start the test
        Test.startTest();

        // Create an instance of the batch class and execute it
        DeactivateInactiveUsersBatch batchJob = new DeactivateInactiveUsersBatch();
        Database.executeBatch(batchJob);

        // Stop the test
        Test.stopTest();

        // Query the updated User records to verify the changes
        List<User> deactivatedUsers = [SELECT Id, IsActive FROM User WHERE IsActive = FALSE];
        
        // Verify that the expected number of users have been deactivated
        System.assertEquals(1, deactivatedUsers.size(), 'All User records should be deactivated');
    }
}

I am writing a test class to deactivate all User records that have not logged in for over a year. However, I am facing an issue because I am unable to set the value for LastLoginDate, receiving an error that User.LastLoginDate is not writable. What could be a workaround to resolve this issue?

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000386257&type=1 or https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/193354/how-can-i-unit-test-the-not-writabble-field
